# 23.04, sftp, and RW

Tags: sftp, 23.04

Is there a way to give a non-root SFTP user read and write of their SFTP root directory?

I tried doing 775, 755, and 644 but these give error or not the desired results.

Comment: chmod u+rwx ./*